# How to include NCCL 2 from NVIDIA in Dockerfiles?

Tags: gpu, dockerfile, nvidia

For `NVIDIA Collective Communications Library` (`NCCL`) version 2, `NVIDIA` asks the user to first register as a developer before getting access to the installation files.

This will bring a challenge on how to install `NCCL` in the containers. For personal use, we can copy the installation file to the container using `Dockerfile` `ADD` command. However, this approach does not seem right for a `Dockerfile` to be used by others (or put in public).

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with oracle installation files, the only way I could think of doing this was to ask the user to manually download the files and then using `Dockerfile` `ONBUILD` command along with the `Dockerfile` `ADD` command within the dockerfile. Meaning every user will essentially have to build their own image but at least the image can be made public without infringing on NVIDIA's policies.

Something like this:

```
FROM example/test:latest
....
ONBUILD ADD /example/nvidia /example/nvidia
....
CMD ['./foo.sh']
```

Then the user would have to use their own dockerfile pulling your public image like so:

```
FROM myrepo/myimage:nvidia
```

Provided they have the **NVIDIA Collective Communications Library** placed in the right folder, they can just run docker build to legally have their own image with Nvidia's libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with the `ONBUILD` scenario. However, it is still based on the `ADD` command (requires the file to present locally).